# Can't create new project in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs

I'm unable to add a new Team Project in TFS 2010:

**Machine 1:**
I have a Virtual Machine which has windows 2008 R2 64 bit installed. The machine name is "staging". I have installed TFS 2010 trial version into it. I installed basic settings of TFS. I have no visual studio installed on this machine.

**Machine 2:**
I have another Virtual Machine which has windows 7 32 bit in it. The Machine name is "Development". I have Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on this machine.

Now I want to create a new team project in "development" by using Visual Studio Team Explorer. I can successfully connected to TFS DefaultCollection. I used server's administrator credentials to connect to the TFS. But as soon as I try to create a new project, I get an error message which says:

> TF30168: The new team project wizard experienced a failure checking your permissions to create project

I tried to add user "everyone" in TFS administration on "staging" for all groups and for each group one by one. But no luck. Then I tried to add local user in TFS in "development" but no luck.

I can provide you more detail if you want.

Comment: Are both VMs in the same domain?

Comment: well I'm not sure what you mean by Domain here. All Machines are  part of a workgroup. Both VMs are running under windows 7 32 bit Host. "Staging" is on VMWare while "Development" is on Virtual PC 007.

Comment: Its Virtual PC 2007 and not Virtual PC 007.

Comment: Check the Security log in the Event Viewer after trying to create a new team project. I barely remember workgroups, but don't you need to have the same account on both systems with the same password? Do you have that set up?

Comment: Keywords Date and Time Source Event ID Task Category
Audit Success 2/1/2012 7:54:37 AM Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4648 Logon "A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:
 Security ID:  Development\noman
 Account Name:  noman
 Account Domain:  Development
 Logon ID:  0x2c093
 Logon GUID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
 Account Name:  Administrator
 Account Domain:  staging
 Logon GUID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Comment: Target Server:
 Target Server Name: staging
 Additional Information: staging

Process Information:
 Process ID:  0xdc8
 Process Name:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Network Information:
 Network Address: -
 Port:   -

This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account’s credentials.  This most commonly occurs in batch-type configurations such as scheduled tasks, or when using the RUNAS command."

Comment: Did that succeed? I notice two different accounts were used.

Comment: Well I have setup a domain now. So now I have the same domain user in both machines (development and staging). I am logged in on both machines with Administrator. But still the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: What does the security log say now? Have you tried actually logging in with the domain accounts you plan to use?

Comment: yes, I have loggged in as domain Administrator on both Staging and Development. I have restarted IIS as well. This time I can't see anything related to this problem in security log. I cleared all the enteries in the security log and recrated the error. But still no entries in security log.

Comment: I found following details in VSTS_TeamprojectCreation log file:

Comment: ---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2012-02-02 11:07:34Z
Module: Wizard
Event Description: TF30249: The New Team Project Wizard could not retrieve the process template information.
Exception Type: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TemplateHeaderRetrievalFailedException
Exception Message: Error retrieving TemplateHeaders from the Team Foundation Server
Stack Trace:

Comment: Wow. Maybe try uploading the process template to a different name, then try to create a project using the new template? Or do the same from an out of the box template.

Comment: Is it happening because I didn't install Team Foundation Build Services?

Comment: I really have no idea. Try installing it and see what happens.

Comment: This is funny. Actually I reinstalled TFS like 5 times on staging. lol. But still the same issue. Now I'm going to install Visual Studio 2010 on staging. And I will try to create a new project in staging. lets see how it goes.

Comment: Problem solved. That was the beta version of VS 2010 I was using on development. I took the trial version of VS 2010 from Microsoft and that worked for me. Now I can create new project. wopps. But thanks for your time and suggestions John.

Comment: If you add this as the answer, then we can upvote it and it won't appear in the list of unanswered posts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a beta version of Visual Studio 2010 to create a new Team Project on a RTM Team Foundation Server. The versions must match.